# Design a simple relational database table to store friends of user information

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a simple user table say with columns

```
user_id PK
Name
```

And a friends table with columns

```
user_id FK
friend_id FK
```

Now say friends table stores

```
Table Friends
---------------
user_id friend_id
----------------
1      2
1      3
2      3
```

The relation of friends is <->
Now to retrieve list of friends of user 1, I can do

```
SELECT friend_id FROM friends where user_id = 1;
```

But since its a two way relationship, how can I retrieve list of friends of user 3 even when it doesn't mention user 3 anywhere in user_id column of friends table with a query? Will I have to do redundant storage like (3,1), (3,2) in friends table?
Or can anyone propose a better schema?

Comment: This can easily be solved using a recursive query. Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Mysql db.
Phong, enlighten please.

Comment: why not make friend_id a primary key?

Comment: if user1 is a friend of user2 then user2 is a friend of user1, if you don't have extra roles like followers then storing both (1,2) and (2,1) is redundant in this case you can store only one of above pairs

Comment: @Phong6698 is probably saying why not make a entity relationship model, but you kinda made one already....

Comment: Yes, thats how I m storing fero. And I wanna know how to retrieve friends of users who are mentioned in friend_id column. Nabmeister, friend_id can not be PK since it can contain more than one same values?

Comment: Ok, it'll be a little long for a comment, let me to write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *user1* is a friend of *user2* then *user2* is a friend of *user1*.

If you don't have extra roles like followers then storing both (1,2) and (2,1) is redundant in this case you can store only one of above pairs and retrieve the friends of users using a `join` and a `union`:

```
select u.user_id user, f1.friend_id friend
from users u
join friends f1 on u.user_id=f1.user_id
union
select u.user_id user, f2.user_id friend
from users u
join friends f2 on u.user_id=f2.friend_id
```